# What is Near block gas limit/target

Tags: nearprotocol

What is Near block gas limit/target?
I want to know what is the max gas per sec Near protocol can handle.
In order to know that I need to know how much gas can fix in the block.

Answer (score 2):

Near gas has an approximate relation to compute time, where 1sec corresponds to 1PGas or 10^15 Gas. [[1](https://docs.near.org/docs/concepts/gas#thinking-in-gas)]

1PTgas is also what is allowed per shard per block. This is configured as `gas_limit` and it can be looked up through an API call [[2](https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc/protocol)] or you can peak at the source on Github [[3](https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/f951d6ed8e491ef842da6bd9448d3242472c126b/nearcore/res/mainnet_genesis.json#L15)]

With current progress, having successfully launched Simple Nightshade, there are 4 shards [[4](https://near.org/blog/near-launches-nightshade-sharding-paving-the-way-for-mass-adoption/)]. That gives you 4Pgas / block. But it can scale up as more shards are added.

Comment: To compare to the Ethereum gas target I can just simply say that the near block gas limit is around 10^15 gas per sec?

Comment: Ethereum gas and Near gas are quite different and cannot be compared 1-to-1. I recommend reading this: https://docs.near.org/docs/concepts/gas#ballpark-comparisons-to-ethereum